# Move an app back on front without changing it?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app that acts as sortofa bridge between two other apps, A and B, both of which are mostly black boxes. The user almost always stays in app A but sometimes needs to do something that my app or app B know how to handle. App A supports external actions via URL so I have a custom scheme://host defined for my app.

If the user does an action that my app handles, I get launched via the URL then do my thing then call finish() and the user's back in app A *where they started* (edit: same activity and etc) - perfect.

If the user does an action that app B handles, my app needs to be in the middle so it can do some translation. App A launches me, I format the message for app B and launch it. When it's done and comes back to my app, I call finish() and.. end up back in app B. Understandable I guess but I really want to end up in app A.

**So the question is**, how to I tell Android to put A back on top/in front without changing it? I can find the URL for app A via getReferrer() but when I put that into an Intent, it acts like I'm restarting app A instead of just going back to where it was. The doc for Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK looked promising but it still acts like a new instance of the app.

It seems like this should totally be possible but I'm not seeing it. Java/api25.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that App B is not ending, returning control to your app. App B is launching your app, putting your app on top of it. When your app finishes, your app goes away revealing the still running App B underneath.

So basically App B has bad behaviour (at least, behaviour that is inappropriate for what you are trying to do).

To solve the problem you can either fix App B, or you can do the following:

Instead of just calling `finish()`, when you want to return to App A just launch it the same way that Android launches an app when the user presses on the app icon:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("package.name.of.app.A");
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

This will bring App A to the front in whatever state it was in when it was put in the background (ie: doesn't actually launch any new `Activity`). If App A isn't running, it will launch the root `Activity` of App A, as if the user pressed the app's icon on the HOME screen.

I'm assuming that both App A and App B are running in separate tasks. If that isn't the case, I'll need you to provide more information about which activities are running in which tasks.

Comment: Is there an Intent flag needed for that? That code acts like it's launching the app from scratch instead of just popping it back on top, in the same Activity it was in.

Comment: The `Intent` that you get from `getLaunchIntentForPackage()` has the necessary flags already set. Pleas eedit your question and add the manifest entries for all the relevant activities.